# webm and mp4 hex file header durations

Tags: hex, mp4, duration, webm, file-header

so, there's a "trick" that lets you manipulate video file durations and I would like to know if there is a way to 100% set the exact duration you want without to much trial and error(?). thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After searching and trying stuff for hours, I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz9cAMxyYro&t=32s).
Look in the comments for *UNICORNTEARZ13*'s thread, and someone named *Stop! You violated the law!* explained that the duration value after marker 44 89 in WebM files is IEEE754 float hexadecimal. I then used [to site](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html) to get the exact value I wanted and voilà !

Comment: damn, thank you so much! i really do appreciate it!